# Limit UIPanGestureRecognizer to 1 object at 1 time in array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

How do i set the panning off when the other object is currently using it?
Eg, when i'm panning on 1 object, the other object should not move. Currently i'm able to pan 2 object.

Another way is to set the panning min touch to 2, which i don't want.

My main code:

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *imagePanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveImage:)];
    imagePanGesture.delegate = self;
    [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:imagePanGesture]; 

    [currentImageArray addObject:tempImageView];



- (void)moveImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
        CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
        CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;

        float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
        CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor), 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));

        finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width);
        finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
            } completion:nil];
    } 
}
```

---

i figured out how to do it. Before panning, compare the view.

```
if(recognizer.view == [currentImageArray objectAtIndex:iCurrentImageTag])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out how to do it. Before panning, compare the view.

```
if(recognizer.view == [currentImageArray objectAtIndex:iCurrentImageTag])
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be in the GestureRecognizer Delegate:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```